# Rails 4 x paper_trail: undefined method for nil:NilClass after destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning, auditing, paper-trail-gem

I just installed the `paper_trail` gem in my Rails 4 app.

So, now I have this in my `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "versions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "item_type",  null: false
  t.integer  "item_id",    null: false
  t.string   "event",      null: false
  t.string   "whodunnit"
  t.text     "object"
  t.datetime "created_at"
end
```

I added `paper_trail` to my `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

A `post` `has_many` `comments` and `belongs_to` a `calendar`.

I am trying to display a history of recently modified posts in my `Calendars#Index` view.

I used the [official documentation](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) and [this tutorial](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Auditing-via-paper_trail-(change-history)) for inspiration.

So, in `calendars_controller.rb`, I have:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @calendars = @user.calendars.all
  @comments = @user.calendar_comments.where.not(user_id: @user.id).order "created_at DESC"
  @versions = PaperTrail::Version.order('id desc').limit(20)
end
```

And in my `Calendar` `index.html.erb` view, I have:

```
<h3 class="main_title">Updates</h3>

    <div id="my_changes">

      <% if @versions.any? %>

        <table id="my_change_table">

          <tr>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> CALENDAR </th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> POST </th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> AUTHOR </th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> CHANGE </th>
          </tr>

          <% @versions.each do |version| %>

          <% post = Post.find_by_id(version.item_id) %>

            <tr>
              <td><%= Calendar.find_by_id(post.calendar_id).name %></td>
              <td><%= post.subject %></td>
              <td><%= User.find_by_id(version.whodunnit).first_name %></td>
              <td><%= version.event.humanize + "d" %></td>
            </tr>

          <% end %>

        </table>

      <% else %>

        <p>There was no change to your posts yet.</p>

      <% end %>

    </div>
```

This works actually pretty well when a user `update`s a post.

However, as soon as a user `destroy`s a post, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Calendars#index
undefined method `item_id' for #<Post:0x007fff22e28c58>
<% post = Post.find_by_id(version.item_id) %>
```

In fact, this makes sense, since we `destroy`ed the `post`, it does not exist any more, so we can retrieve its `id`.

But I thought this was precisely `paper_trail`'s job.

So, I must be missing something.

I tried to use the `version.reify` and the `version.previous` methods, but still ran into the same issue.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: might there be a misalignment between the code in the error to the one you posted? `<% post = Post.find_by_id(version.reify.item_id) %>` vs.`<% post = Post.find_by_id(version.item_id) %>` ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I was trying different things while I was asking the questions, which resulted in a mix up, sorry about that. I just updated the question with the code as it should be. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after you destroy an object, reify will rerun a new instance of the object, which is unsaved and has no id.

Since it is deleted anyway you should expect `Post.find_by_id(version.item_id)` to not find it anyway.

**Edit**

You should be able to get the properties of the original object from the version (see [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#choosing-attributes-to-monitor))

So you can change your code to something like (assuming all of the versions in your system are calendars) and I think it should work:

```
      <% @versions.each do |version| %>

      <% post = version.reify %>

        <tr>
          <td><%= Calendar.find_by_id(post.calendar_id).name %></td>
          <td><%= post.subject %></td>
          <td><%= User.find_by_id(version.whodunnit).first_name %></td>
          <td><%= version.event.humanize + "d" %></td>
        </tr>

      <% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand what you say and it makes sense. What I am trying to achieve is to display a list of the changes that were applied — eg: saved — to each post object. The problem, currently, is that I can't seem to retrieve the id of an object after it was destroyed. And that is confusing me, since I thought that was precisely what paper_trail was for. May I ask you if what I want to achieve is actually possible?

Comment: What you can do if all you want is to display the verstion in the UI is to call reify which will give you an unsaved object that corresponds to that version and just display it in the UI. No need to look for the object in the database

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Should I use a `before_filter` on the `destroy` action to get the `id` of the `post` then? Isn't there any way to achieve this directly with `paper_trail`?

Comment: Hum, not sure I understand your comment. Just to be clearer that my original question may have been, what I want is to display in the Calendars#Index view is something like "David destroyed post #12 from calendar #4". Does that make sense?

Comment: If all you want is to display the content of the version in the UI you can navigate the versions and query the attribute you want to display directly on the version https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: Well, I am not sure it is the content of the version. Because I need the subject of the post that was destroyed, and to get that, I need to do something like `Post.find_by_id(version.item_id).subject`. Which is what is causing my issue I guess. Would you mind switching to the chat, because I feel like I am getting something wrong about how paperclip works?

Comment: see my edit. I think this should work (I'm not sure about associations, so post.calendar_id is still in question)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted.